# Encrypted .dmg file password no longer working - even older versions

Tags: mac, encryption, passwords

I have an encrypted 10mb .dmg file on my Mac.

The password is the same as the password I use to login to the very laptop I am typing this is on.

The .dmg won't open and tells me the password is incorrect. I have tried multiple times with the same result.

[image]

I have:

1. Restarted in safe mode. The problem persists.
2. Used different keyboard. Still have the same problem.
3. Downloaded a version of the file from Google Drive backup that is several versions old that I had previously opened successfully. That old version now gives me the same error.

I am on MacOS Sonoma.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The file is probably corrupted. With your backups you could probably get a good idea at what point it became corrupted. A corrupted encrypted package is often indicated by the password being "incorrect" when it is, in fact, not.

Comment: By downloading a version several versions ago, that would mean I was able to open it and it wasn't corrupted.

Comment: Yea, and that means the most apparent difference between that file and the one you're having problems opening, assuming you are correct to say you are entering the password correctly and the same, is that the current one is corrupted.

Comment: No, I can't open any file. Old, new, backed up, nothing.

Comment: So they're all corrupt or the password is wrong.

Comment: Is it possible the file is being corrupted during upload, on Google's server, or in download? *One bit* difference can make an encrypted file unusable. Do you have a local copy to compare? If not, make a DMG file, keep a local copy, and send it up to Google drive and download, and compare the two, to see if that is the source of the issue.